# Allowable abbreviations list in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, abbreviation

We have some abbreviations we regularly use in our code base around product names (e.g. everyone refers to Big Long Product Name as "BLM" and in code we have classes like BLMDataParser).

Sonar flags all such classes wanting them to be BlmDataParser.

Visual Studio and ReSharper both have allowable abbreviation lists, but I can't find the similar Sonar functionality. Am I just missing this somewhere?

Comment: What is the id of that rule? I thought you meant `squid:S00101`, but that one requires matching the regex `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`, which your example passes.

Comment: It's csharpsquid:S101

Comment: @Belizzle Hey, I have the same problem, how did you solve it?

Comment: @BorysFursov was never able to solve it. We just ignored them waiting for the day that Sonar allowed them to be ignored.